# How to iterate over Python enum ignoring "deprecated" ones?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

If I have an enum class set up like this

```
class fruits(enum.IntEnum):
    apples = 0
    bananas = 1  # deprecated
    pears = 2  # deprecated
    strawberries = 3
```

Is there a way to dynamically get the enum's that are not deprecated (basically only fetch apples and strawberries? They're only marked via comment, and I prefer not to create a set of "deprecated" notifs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need some extra code to support that use-case.  I'll show it using [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/)<sup>1</sup>:

```
from aenum import IntEnum

class Fruits(IntEnum):
    _init_ = 'value active'
    #
    apples = 0, True
    bananas = 1, False  # deprecated
    pears = 2, False    # deprecated
    strawberries = 3, True
    #
    @classmethod
    def active(cls):
        return [m for m in cls if m.active]
    #
    @classmethod
    def deprecated(cls):
        return [m for m in cls if not m.active]
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(Fruits)
[<Fruits.apples: 0>, <Fruits.bananas: 1>, <Fruits.pears: 2>, <Fruits.strawberries: 3>]

>>> Fruits.apples
<Fruits.apples: 0>

>>> Fruits.bananas
<Fruits.bananas: 1>

>>> Fruits.active()
[<Fruits.apples: 0>, <Fruits.strawberries: 3>]

>>> Fruits.deprecated()
[<Fruits.bananas: 1>, <Fruits.pears: 2>]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library *(a drop-in replacement for the stdlib `enum`)*.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, not with this setup
comments will not modify anything about your code and they are solely for user use.