# How do I detect and invoke a function when a python enum member is accessed

Tags: python, enums, deprecation-warning

I have an enum for which some of the members are deprecated:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Foo(Enum):
    BAR = "bar"
    BAZ = "baz"  # deprecated
```

How do it get the following behavior:

- When somebody writes `Foo.BAR`, everything behaves normally
- When somebody writes `Foo.BAZ`, a `DeprecationWarning` is issued using `warnings.warn("BAZ is deprecated", DeprecationWarning)`. Afterwards everything behaves normally.
- The same behavior should apply when members are accessed in other ways, e.g. `Foo("baz")` and `Foo["BAZ"]` should raise a `DeprecationWarning`.

Things I have tried, but failed:

- Overwrite `_missing_` and don't define `BAZ`. Does not work, because in the end I still need to return an existing member for a while (until our DB is cleaned of the deprecated value).
  But I can not dynamically add members to an enum. If I define it, `_missing_` is not called.
- overwrite any of `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__`. These are called when accessing attributes of a member, e.g. `Foo.BAZ.boo`, not when accessing `Foo.BAZ`. I guess this could work if I could overwrite `__getattr__` of `EnumMeta` and then make `Enum` use the child meta class. However, I don't see how that can be done either
- overwrite `__class_getitem__`: Reserved for static typing and not called anyways.
- Abuse `_generate_next_value_`. This function is only called on class creation, so I can get a deprecation warning when the class is called once, regardless of whether the deprecated member is called or not. But that is not what I want.
- Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057421/how-to-iterate-over-python-enum-ignoring-deprecated-ones). It does not solve my problem, as the goal there is filtering of deprecated members during iteration.

TLDR: How can I detect and invoke a function when an enum member is accessed?

I am working with python 3.8, so new features are fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to be one of those times when [subclassing `EnumMeta`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43730305/208880) is the right thing to do.

The new metaclass will run an `_on_access` method, if it exists, whenever a member is accessed:

```
class OnAccess(EnumMeta):
    """
    runs a user-specified function whenever member is accessed
    """
    #
    def __getattribute__(cls, name):
        obj = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if isinstance(obj, Enum) and obj._on_access:
            obj._on_access()
        return obj
    #
    def __getitem__(cls, name):
        member = super().__getitem__(name)
        if member._on_access:
            member._on_access()
        return member
    #
    def __call__(cls, value, names=None, *, module=None, qualname=None, type=None, start=1):
        obj = super().__call__(value, names, module=module, qualname=qualname, type=type, start=start)
        if isinstance(obj, Enum) and obj._on_access:
            obj._on_access()
        return obj
```

The new base `Enum` treats any extra arguments on member creation as arguments for a `deprecate` function, and sets the `_on_access` attribute to that function only if extra arguments are given:

```
class DeprecatedEnum(Enum, metaclass=OnAccess):
    #
    def __new__(cls, value, *args):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member._args = args
        member._on_access = member.deprecate if args else None
        return member
    #
    def deprecate(self):
        args = (self.name, ) + self._args
        import warnings
        warnings.warn(
                "member %r is deprecated; %s" % args,
                DeprecationWarning,
                stacklevel=3,
                )
```

And our example `Enum` with deprecated members:

```
class Foo(DeprecatedEnum):
    BAR = "bar"
    BAZ = "baz", "use something else"
```

And the warnings (from a test script):

```
# no warning here
list(Foo)

# nor for non-deprecated members
Foo.BAR

# but direct use of deprecated members does generate warnings
Foo.BAZ
/home/ethan/test:74: DeprecationWarning: member 'BAZ' is deprecated; use something else
  Foo.BAZ

Foo('baz')
/home/ethan/test:75: DeprecationWarning: member 'BAZ' is deprecated; use something else
  Foo('baz')

Foo['BAZ']
/home/ethan/test:76: DeprecationWarning: member 'BAZ' is deprecated; use something else
  Foo['BAZ']
```

And all the deprecated members in `Foo`:

```
>>> print([m.name for m in Foo if m._args])
['BAZ']
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. I would like to use this approach and also allow to use `auto()` for enum values. Do you have a hint how to let `auto` processing on the base class?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.  Please ask a new question (and possibly reference this one).

Comment: I just wanted to use auto generated enum values, like `BAZ = enum.auto(), "use something else"`. But then in the value I have the `<enum.auto object ...>` instead of an auto generated value. But maybe it's caused by Python version I use - https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.auto - seems that it might work from python 3.11.1.

Comment: @Mi-La: Yup, that was fixed in 3.11.1.